# Phone gap, to much javascript?

Tags: javascript, cordova

So for the phonegap/cordova application the I am currently working on I am writing A LOT of javascript, when doing things like importing the scripts there is so much I needed to make an import script instead of adding script tags to the top because it would be inefficient for me as a programmer to add a new script to every single page instead of just adding it to this one.

Now my question is, could I be using to much javascript? Is lets say 20 files of js to much? 500 + lines each (excluding the import script). I can see this increasing in the future as well. So what would you say the maximum should be? Should I be keep the amount of scripts down and just putting it all in one and minifying it etc. Since the js is running straight from the phone that wouldn't really matter would it?

Comment: That all depends on the quality of the code, really: if you're including 10 files of 100 lines of terribly inefficient code (with `eval` and 101 global variables, with conflicting names and what have you) then, yes, that's definitly too much. If your JS is well-written, it shouldn't be a problem for most devices. But honestly: manually adding script-tags to all pages: why not have your server determine what scripts are needed on each page?

Comment: I would do server side imports if I could, however I am using phone gap, no server side. All client. Thats why I have a js file doing client side imports

Comment: fair point :) forget about that, but the most important thing in your case still is: make sure your JS code is well-written. That should go without saying, of course

Comment: I believe my js is well written. Wouldn't know however as it is all self taught. Are there actual good validators for js?

Comment: On the whole: jslint isn't bad, though it tends to treat things that Douglas Crockford doesn't like as errors (like ++ and --, or regex's with [^a-z], and . in them), most annoyingly it's very strict on white-space, but you can switch those naggers off. Also: Google's closure compiler will generate wanrings when using "unsafe" constructors and such, so if jslint manages to scan your code all the way down (without saying something like: "too many errors 50% scanned") and the closure compiler can minify your code, then it's ok

Comment: Sweet as. Thanks. Will have a look. I will try my best to make it efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the script loading doesn't delay your app loading, IMO it's ok to have all the code you need to. 
The fact of separating the script into the files you need will probably make your app slower, but it will improve maintainability and understanding of the app itself (could be for yourself in the future or for another programmers)

Comment: So while in development I could have it all in their separate scripts, then when I go to deploy I should minify it etc?

Comment: @SmartLemon: No, don't use obfuscators... even minifying is not always the best way forward (as production and development scripts differ, source version control can become tricky, and 1 huge script might cause issues (functions/functions get redefined etc...)

Comment: For development it won't be in all one file. As we have discussed. The only point it will be in one is when it is deployed. Therefore for development there should be no problem. Debugging isn't a problem. Any problem can be back tracked.

Comment: You would move it into one script first, then minify/obfuscate

Comment: But really obfuscation wouldn't matter when it comes to phone gap would it? As the client would never be able to see the script, but then we get the reverse engineers.

Comment: As per Yahoo and Google recomendations, you should minify your script. Obfuscation, as you said, is useful when the final user actually is available to see the client code(i.e pc browsers). In this particular case(phonegap) I don't believe would be neccesary. I would recommend to benchmark the app with and without obfuscating, because velocity would be the only improvement over there.

Comment: @EricFrick: Obfuscating doesn't improve the performance, and _shouldn't_ slow it down, if it's done well... The only performance benefit you stand is shorten the time it takes to download and parse the JS code, as soon as the code is ready to run, your code will run as fast as it can, obfuscated or not

Comment: The purpose of obfuscation is to make it illegible, there shouldn't be any performance increase, actually I would expect for their to be a decrease, or though it would be anything to worry about. As for magnification wouldn't that just improve "download" speeds of the scripts as you are downloading less characters, with small scripts I don't think this would matter, however with larger scripts like mine it would make a pretty big difference really.